# how to fix CommunityToolkit Maui missing assembly for andoird - .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, android, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I've a .NET MAUI project setup with the nuget packages for CommunityToolkit.

it says that it's not available for android.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of your CommunityToolkit.Maui requires Android or other platform dependencies to be net7.0

You can see the [comparison of two different versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI8Gx.jpg).

**Update .NET MAUI to .NET 7**

Open your .NET MAUI app csproj file and find your the TargetFrameworks node(s):

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
       ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

Replace net6.0 with net7.0:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
       ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

Save the csproj file at last.